# Web API response - add attribute and change xml tag name

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to learn Web API and I tried the following code and it works as expected when I access http://localhost:50737/api/persons

Person Model

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int? DigitID { get; set; }
}
```

Person Controller

```
public class PersonController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/persons")]
    public IList<Person> GetAllPersons()
    {
        return new List<Person>() { new Person() {FirstName = "My First Name 1" }, new Person() {FirstName = "My First Name 2" } };
    }
}
```

XML Response

```
<ArrayOfPerson>
    <Person>
        <DigitID i:nil="true"/>
        <FirstName>My First Name 1</FirstName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <DigitID i:nil="true"/>
        <FirstName>My First Name 2</FirstName>
    </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

I added   `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;` to global.asax which in turn removed the LastName but not the DigitID

Here I need to

1. Change the ArrayOfPerson to "Persons"
2. Add an attribute "Count" that holds the total number of persons returned.
3. Remove the null element from the XML response

So the expected XML response will be

```
<Persons Count=2>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>My First Name 1</FirstName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>My First Name 2</FirstName>
    </Person>
</Persons>
```

How do I do the same in JSON as at the end I need to support only JSON

Answer (score 0):

for Q1:
use this - `[return: MessageParameter(Name = "Persons")]` as an `attribute` to your `operation`.

for Q3: change `DigitID` to `Int` or else it'll keep coming in your response because you mark it a `Nullable type`.